# ASP.net Login control Help

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am playing around withe supplied login control in visual studio 2008. I am trying to create some failuretext and have it display on login error but i can never get the failure text to display.  Can anyone give me a quick run down on how this control works.

Why wont the failuretext show?  Thanks for the help.

Here is some simple code...

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               //user object that does the user validation
                _clsUser = new AdvantageUI.Classes.User();
                _clsUser.ValidateLoginAttempt(lgnLogin.UserName, lgnLogin.Password);  //if login failed exception thrown with error text.

                e.Authenticated = true;
//for use on additional pages as we will want to make sure user is valid and logged in.
                Session.Add("User", _clsUser);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lgnLogin.FailureText=ex.Message;

                //lgnLogin.DataBind();
            }

                Response.Redirect("ACBAdmin.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: It's not good practice to use `try...catch` exceptions to handle your control flow.

Comment: There is never a reason to have a namespace named `Classes`

Comment: That was me being lazy as far as the namespace goes.  Thanks for point that those out.  As far as not using try...catch.  There are 3 errors that can occur.  would you simply stop processing when one of them occurs using a case statement or something to control the flow?

Comment: I tried putting some bogus junk in the failure text just before the try catch and it sill doesn't display?

Comment: It was just a general observation. I'm not familiar with the `AdvantageUI` library, but if `ValidateLoginAttempt` returns a boolean, that should be checked with an `if..else`. If you know there are three exceptions, you should catch each exception individually before using the `catch all` exception. It's not compulsory, just a suggestion for cleaner code :)

Comment: I moved it outside the try...catch and it worked....thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redirecting after your try/catch.

Comment: I am not certain how that affects filling the failuretext property, but i moved this within the try catch and still no failuretext when the login attempt fails?